# jsPDF / html2canvas: Fit long image to one page or increase height of generated PDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I have a long image (1000px x 3572px) and am using the following code:

```
function generatePdf() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('print-div')).then(function (canvas) {
        canvas.id = "canvas-print";
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
        const imgProps= doc.getImageProperties(img);
        const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
        const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
        doc.save('test.pdf');        
    });
}
```

This sizes the image proportionally, but half the image still gets cut off.

How can I make sure that the height of the images fits into the PDF, or scale the PDF height so it matches the image?

Thanks!

Comment: If the image is always higher than it is wide, get its height and calculate a proportional width out of it, instead of the other way around.

Comment: Thanks - so what would I need to change?

Comment: Instead of using a fixed width and calculating the height, use a fixed height and calculate the width.